# Sum of the series $1/2 + 1/6 + 1/42 + 1/(42 \times 43) + ...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I get the summation of the following series?

$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{\underbrace{3\times4}_{=12}} + \frac{1}{\underbrace{12\times13}_{=156}} + \frac{1}{\underbrace{156\times157}_{=24492}} + ...$

$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\underbrace{2\times3}_{=6}} + \frac{1}{\underbrace{6\times7}_{=42}} + \frac{1}{\underbrace{42\times43}_{=1806}} + ...$

Comment: What are your thoughts? By the way, you forgot to use ```$ $``` in your title.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog, Thanks, I edited the title. And, I have no idea at the moment.

Comment: @clathratus, I think the pattern is clear; each denominator is resulted by the multiplication of (the previous denominator) by (the sum of the previous denominator and 1)

Comment: So it is kind of telescoping

Comment: @Certainlynotadog though not actually telescoping. Each term is about $c^{2^n}$ for some $c$ so you get fast convergence of the series

Comment: Okay so the $n$-th term is $1/a(n)$ where $a(n+1)=a(n)^2+a(n)$ and $a(0)$ is either $2$ or $3$. This is sequence [A004168](https://oeis.org/A004168) in the OEIS.

Comment: @clathratus, Thanks for the link. In this link, it's just considering the denominator numbers as a series. I'm looking for the sum of the mentioned series...

Comment: @Pooya yes. Perhaps, knowing that the denominators are iterates of a polynomial, we can hope to learn more about the sum itself. Perhaps it is not enough for a closed form, but we can probabl get some good estimates

Comment: I did some digging on the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A082732), and found that if we define $$\alpha(n)=\text{LCM}\left\{\alpha(k):1\le k<n\right\},$$
where $\alpha(1)=1$, $\alpha(2)=3$, then for $n\ge0$
$$q(n)=\alpha(n+3)-1$$ and $$\frac13=\sum_{n\ge3}\frac{1}{\alpha(n)}.$$ There may be a closed form...

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but in my last comment, the series you are trying to evaluate is $\sum_{n\ge0}1/q(n)$